# How in PHP can i edit the variable in a way to extract a value from it, for further use?

Tags: php, phpseclib

How can I edit the variable in a way to extract a value from it, for further use?

As you can see in the code, after the script worked I have a value named result, which were taken from the buffer. Now i need to extract a specific field from this value ($result) for further use.
The value $result contains a printout in a format " a=xxxxxx b=yyyyyyy c=zzzzzzz . so i need to extract only the "b=", i.e. the value that "b=" holds.

Is it possible to do this? I will need to just one value which comes in the middle of the printout. The rest should be deleted.

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('hostname');
if (!$ssh->login('xxx', 'xxxxx')){
        exit('Login Failed');
        }
$value = $_POST['value'];


ob_start();     
echo $ssh->exec('xxxxxxxx '.$value.' xxxxxxxx');
$result = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();
echo $result;
```

Comment: Without knowing what `$result` contains, it's hard, if not impossible, to answer your question.

Comment: What is the result type?  Is it JSON?  Is it text?  Are you sending headers?  If it's json, it needs to be decoded, and then use $json['key'], if its not, find the value you want with [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Comment: Sorry guys, i'm kinda new in php. and this is my first project. The value $result contains a printout in a format " a=xxxxxx b=yyyyyyy c=zzzzzzz . so i need to extract only the "b=yyyyyy" part.

Comment: as i said i'm new around, and as it becomes more clearer, i'm editing my question, by adding additinal details.

Comment: @Ashot Avetisyan - why are you messing with the output buffer? You could just do `$result = $ssh->exec('xxxxxxxx '.$value.' xxxxxxxx');`

Comment: Hi. Yup i've alerady figured it out, and optimized that part. but thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could explode the result string into an array. Something like this should help.

```
$array = explode(' ',$result); //assuming whitespace is the separator for each
                               //item and there is no whitespace in the values.
foreach($array as $item)
{
    $data = explode('=',$item);
    if($data[0] == 'b') //search for the key you need
      break;
}
echo $data[1]; //output the value (in this case: 'yyyyyyy')
```

You can also try with a string search. This might work better for you:

```
$array = explode(' ',$result);
foreach($array as $item)
{
    if(stristr($item,'GTI='))
    {
        $data = $item;
        break;
    }
}
echo $data;
```

**UPDATE**
To get other values in the string, one way would be to build an array of key=>value pairs:

```
$array = explode(' ',$result); 
$data = array();
foreach($array as $item)
{
    $pair = explode('=',$item);
    $data[$pair[0]] = $pair[1]; // build array like array('a'=>'xxxxx','b'=>'yyyyy',c'=>'zzzzz')
}
// then access the values by the key
echo $data['a'];
echo '<br/>';
echo $data['b'];
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried that, and i received a value, although not the one i need. I don't know how, but the function returns the last value and not the one i've declared. for example i've delcared if($data[0] == 'GTI=') and it returns me "state=".

Comment: Is it in the format 'GTI=VALUE'? If you explode by '=' then `$data[0]` should contain 'GTI' (without the '=' sign) and `$data[1]` would contain 'VALUE'

Comment: exactly! the format is "GTI=VALUE". however, when i explode by "=" it give me the value of the last variable in the printout, no matter which value i'm putting in here if($data[0] == 'b').

Comment: @AshotAvetisyan In your comment above you have `if($data[0] == 'GTI=')` Change that to `if($data[0] == 'GTI')` Also, I've added a secondary solution using string searching. Both options should work for you.

Comment: Hi. I've tried with GTI and GTI= as well non of them helped. I've noticed another strange thing. I've tried to if($data[0] == 'MNT') and it worked (First suggested code), as well as the other values, except of the GTI. The only difference in the values is that GTI is alphanumeric (value in HEX format), but still i can't figure out why  it shouldn't work correctly because of the alphanumeric value.

Comment: The second version of the code worked completely unexpected, it just randomly copied the values without any logic...

Comment: @AshotAvetisyan Can you post a copy of the data file somewhere so I can test it, or an excerpt of it? Perhaps it is something I'm not seeing in the data itself.

Comment: Hi. I've decided to change the approach and to callculate the data based on other parameters in the array. Kyro's "explode" idea helped alot, however, now i've stuck in a position when i only can see "data[0] and data[1] in the array. What needs to be changed to be able to see other values? it might sound easy (stupid), however, i'm stuck in a loop with this :). Thanks!